# Running wiring for a dishwasher

Tags: electrical, wiring, plumbing, dishwasher

I installed a new dishwasher, and now I'm at the point where I need to wire it As a temporary measure, I just wired an appliance cord, and ran it to an outlet.  To do that, I'm running it to an extension cord, out a cabinet, and above the dishwasher.  It's not ideal.  Rather than put in a new outlet under the sink, I'd like to hard wire the dishwasher to its own circuit on the panel in the basement.  My question is, can I drop the Romex through the floor behind the dishwasher?  I know that if you run it to an outlet, the outlet has to be in a separate cabinet, so you can access it without pulling the dishwasher out.  The issue is that it's going to be a real pain in the butt to send it into the wall, then drill a hole down to the basement.  It would be much easier to send it through the floor behind the dishwasher; I just want to make sure that's okay before I do it that way.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: I take it your dishwasher has a wiring compartment on the back that will accept a hardwired connection? What make/model is it, for that matter?

Answer (score 2):

I have done that, hole in the floor back near the wall,

[MC Modular Whip](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-8-ft-12-2-MC-Modular-Whip/1000057825)  to a junction box in the crawlspace and then romex from the junction box to the panel.

I did not hard wire the whip into the dishwasher, i installed a  surface mounted metal outlet box and connected the whip to that and then a regular appliance cord from the dishwasher to the outlet.

The appliance cord will make the installation and removal of the dishwasher easier as the MC is stiff and will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

> As a temporary measure, I just wired an appliance cord, and ran it to an outlet. To do that, I'm running it to an extension cord, out a cabinet, and above the dishwasher. It's not ideal. Rather than put in a new outlet under the sink, I'd like to hard wire the dishwasher to its own circuit on the panel in the basement.

That's not safe and not code complaint anywhere, that's likely going to end badly...

> I know that if you run it to an outlet, the outlet has to be in a separate cabinet, so you can access it without pulling the dishwasher out.

Per what guidelines?

> The issue is that it's going to be a real pain in the butt to send it into the wall, then drill a hole down to the basement. It would be much easier to send it through the floor behind the dishwasher; I just want to make sure that's okay before I do it that way.

You must follow the manufactures guidelines, if the manufacturer states it's to be hard wired then you can't place a plug onto it. If the guidelines state it's to be corded (highly unlikely) then you use an appropriately rated appliance cord and install it according to the NEC with it's own  dedicated and separate GFCI  branch circuit.

If you're not pulling a permit or hiring an electrician you're going to end up with a homeowners insurance claim that's denied after the house fire... Don't use extension cord for ANYTHING and especially don't use it to connect high amperage appliances like a dish washer.

Most extension cords are 16 gauge (some are even 18 gauge) and you're drawing way more current than that cord is rated for. It's not rated for in wall use, it's not rated for concealed use, and if it overheats it won't self extinguish and it will burn your home to the ground.